# How do I fix shift operator syntax error?

Tags: compiler-errors, verilog, system-verilog, bit-shift

I am trying to compile my code, but I am getting errors when using the arithmetic right shift operator: `>>>`. Here is the code:

```
if (from_id_hmic[117:115]==3'b011)
begin
  reg_stat[rt[0]]>>>1'b1; 
end
```

Here is the error:

```
Error: E:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0/examples/hmic.v(86): near ">>>": syntax error, unexpected >>>
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an incomplete Verilog statement. You need to make an assignment.  Just trying to perform a shift is insufficient, just as `a + 2;` is an incomplete statement.  You probably want something like this:

```
result = reg_stat[rt[0]]>>>1'b1;
```

or perhaps:

```
reg_stat[rt[0]] >>>= 1'b1;
```

`>>>=` is a "binary arithmetic shift assignment operator" (refer to IEEE Std 1800-2009 "Operators and data types").